# How to store unix timestamp as int with default and on update?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been updating my MySQL tables with the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE logs ADD COLUMN updateTimeStamp timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp;
```

This stores the timestamp in the format of

```
2021-12-29 15:21:34
```

I tried originally to do the alter like so:

```sql
ALTER TABLE logs ADD COLUMN updateTimeStamp timestamp DEFAULT unix_timestamp() ON UPDATE unix_timestamp();
```

so that could store like 12121232, however that results in an error.

Is there anyway I can achieve the default and on update and store the timestamp in the format of 1212112, instead of the human readable datetime?

I know I can do `SELECT unix_timestamt(columnname)`, but ideally I don't want to do that.

Comment: According to the documentation, MySQL stores a [TIMESTAMP: A four-byte integer representing seconds UTC since the epoch ('1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html). When you query it, it will give you a timestamp that is humanly readable. If you want to store an integer without MySQL knowing that it's a timestamp, then you could do that, but you'll lose any functionality that it provided with the timestamps.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically get an integer when you select the column, you need to make it an `int` (or `int unsigned`) type.  You can set its default with `default (unix_timestamp())` (the extra parentheses are needed when not using one of the historically allowed default values).  And you will need to add a trigger to set it on update.

But I suggest you not do that; just use a timestamp type.  You just make future trouble for yourself by not using the type designed to store timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am doing as you suggest and keep the timestap as it is

Comment: I tried `ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY created_at int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())` but mysql complains this would ne incorrect syntax.

Can you show, how you defined UNIX_TIMESTAMP as default?

Comment: @Radon8472 what does `select version();` show?  if you are running a very old version of mysql, you may not be able to use more complex expressions as defaults

Comment: @ysth it shows `5.7.12-log`

Comment: @Radon8472 mysql 5.7 has reached end of life and is no longer receiving security updates; you should consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as you can.  in 5.7 you can only specify specific values for an int column default.  again, I suggest you not use an int column to store datetimes.